# No navigation in iframe with Angular 4 and Foundation 6

Tags: angular, http, iframe, https

I'm using an iframe to show some link of website in my angular project.

The problem is that it's impossible to navigate on the target website inside the iframe

here is the code that show the iframe :

```
 <button class="buttonhome" data-open="myModal">Biroute Clic sur ce bouton</button>
    <div class="large reveal" id="myModal" style="height: 85vh" data-reveal>
        <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.digitick.com/cloakroom-invite-soiree-le-rex-club-paris-05-octobre-2017-css5-rexclub-pg101-ri4869965.html" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close modal" type="button">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
```

THe problem is that the website is shown in the iframe, but it's impossible to navigate in it when the user click on a link (it's for buying ticket with redirection). When i try to click on something that should trigger an action, nothing happen.

Any idea ?

EDIT : 
Console browser error :

```
cloakroom-invite-soiree-le-rex-club-paris-05-octobre-2017-css5-rexclub-
pg101-ri4869965.html:1 Mixed Content: The page at 
'https://yunofrontraf-biroute78.c9users.io/homepage' was loaded over 
HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://www.rexclub.com/'. 
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

EDIT2 :

EDIT : I tried with another link and it works, appear that the website i was pointing to does not support https ..

Is this possible to bypass that ?

Comment: Iframe has some problem with angular, you can look into there document

Comment: Does the browser console show any error?

Comment: @ChristianBenseler I updated with the console error. Looks like a problem of security between http and https
It's strange because in my code it's an https link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is nothing related with Angular, Foundation or whatever.
The problem is that the parent is being served from a https and the iframr, http. You can't mix it, this is called "mixed active content" and is blocked by the browser.
Take a look [here](http://www.tinywebgallery.com/blog/iframe-do-not-mix-http-and-https).